# Can I get magnet link for a particular file in a torrent having multiple files in it?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, magnet, magnet-links

Most torrents have multiple files in it. My question is that can i get magnet link of a one particular file in a torrent?

Comment: Sounds like a mild case of [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you really asking how to download only one file in a torrent?  If so, many torrent clients let you mark files as "don't download" once the torrent has loaded.

Comment: If you are like me and want to use online torrent downloader you can try offcloud.com(10GB) & seedr.cc(2GB) zbigz.com (1GB)

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to do that but with `utorrent` you can choose to download only the desired files.

While adding a torrent, you can select which files you want to download as shown:.[image]

You can also do this even if all files were previously selected.
Click on the torrent that you're downloading in the list then select **Files** tab, and then right click on the file that you don't want to download and then select not to download it as shown below:
  [image]